# Using hebrew font in processing

Tags: fonts, processing, hebrew

I'm using a Hebrew typeface called "Drogolin" and in Processing to create text

While some fonts work fine, Drogolin creates ▯ characters instead.

This is the code I'm using:

```
  hebFont = createFont("Drogolin", 32);
  textFont(hebFont);
  fill(0);

void draw() {
      text("המשכן", 0, 40);
}
```

Any Ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is Drogolin on your machine in a place where Processing can find it?

Comment: yes it's installed in my windows fonts folder

here's the original (not for commercial use)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B454RJ8qKV38TDBDbHUxZHpKRFk

Answer (score 0):

[Your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ0Fp.png) seems to work for me as expected.
You could try loading the font from a file instead ([download the font](http://www.world-fonts.com/font/show/guttman-drogolin-normal-1-0-tue-mar-03-07-46-31-1998)) and put in your sketch data folder. Hope that helps.

```
hebFont = createFont("Drogolin.ttf", 30);
```

Comment: I'm using a different version of Drogolin (not fo commercial use - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B454RJ8qKV38TDBDbHUxZHpKRFk)

The Guttman version is working but it's not as good as the other one that doesn't work